# Magento 2 : How to Create Simple Product by UpgradeSchema?

Tags: magento2, product, setup-script, upgradeschema

How do I create a simple product programmatically using `UpgradeSchema`?

Answer (score 1):

I have done with `InstallData` script (the same logic for `UpgradeSchema` script)

app/code/Vendor/Product/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Product\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $productType = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $data = [
            'name' => 'Test',
            'sku'  => 'sku001',
            'price' => 456,
            'weight' => 1
        ];
        $attributeSetId = 4; //Attribute set default
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $product->setData($data);
        $product
            ->setTypeId($this->productType)
            ->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId)
            ->setWebsiteIds([$this->storeManager->getDefaultStoreView()->getWebsiteId()])
            ->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            ->setStockData(['is_in_stock' => 1, 'manage_stock' => 0, 'qty' => 100])
            ->setStoreId(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);

        if (empty($data['visibility'])) {
            $product->setVisibility(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        }
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

A good sample here: https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogSampleData/Model/Product.php